# Facebook-ios-sdk with embedded UIWebView

Tags: facebook, ios, uiwebview

I'm working with the new facebook-ios-sdk and have successfully integrated the api into my native app.  I am able to authenticate a user and properly setup permissions using a popup dialog with the ios-sdk classes.

For a portion of my app I need to use the facebook connection within a `UIWebView`, using javascript and html to process data within the webview.  Given that the user is already logged in and authenticated via the above routine, I would have assumed that the `UIWebView` would share those credentials, or that there would at least be some way to pass or assign the credentials to the webview.

Unfortunately, I found this earlier post which seems to suggest that this scheme doesn't quite work ([iOS - being logged-in in a webView after logging in with the SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236115/ios-being-logged-in-in-a-webview-after-logging-in-with-the-sdk)).  Has anyone else encountered this and/or found a work around?  This seems like it would be a fairly straightforward use case given that I'm not trying to launch mobile safari or something like that - it's all within the same native app.

It just seems like there must be some sort of easy trick or setting that I'm missing.  Maybe somehow setting cookies in the new `UIWebView`?  or something like this?

Comment: This is my problem too, but looks like there is no hope for an answer :(

Comment: almost 2 years later,I'm having the same problem. Any solution in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

**--BY this way Facebook-ios-sdk**

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *chk;

```
@end

@implementation SettingsViewController
@synthesize chk,viewFbLogin;
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell;
AppDelegate *appDelegate;
UIViewController *tweetComposer;
ACAccount *twitterAccount;
ACAccountStore *account;
ACAccountType *accountType;
NSArray *arrayOfAccounts ;
int arr_row_num;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
           }
    return self;
}


- (void)storeAccountWithAccessToken:(NSString *)token secret:(NSString *)secret
{
    //  Each account has a credential, which is comprised of a verified token and secret
    ACAccountCredential *credential =
    [[ACAccountCredential alloc] initWithOAuthToken:token tokenSecret:secret];

    //  Obtain the Twitter account type from the store
    accountType =
    [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    //  Create a new account of the intended type
    twitterAccount = [[ACAccount alloc] initWithAccountType:accountType];

    //  Attach the credential for this user
    twitterAccount.credential = credential;

    //  Finally, ask the account store instance to save the account
    //  Note: that the completion handler is not guaranteed to be executed
    //  on any thread, so care should be taken if you wish to update the UI, etc.
    [account saveAccount:twitterAccount withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            // we've stored the account!
            NSLog(@"the account was saved!");
        }
        else {
            //something went wrong, check value of error
            NSLog(@"the account was NOT saved");

            // see the note below regarding errors...
            //  this is only for demonstration purposes
            if ([[error domain] isEqualToString:ACErrorDomain]) {

                // The following error codes and descriptions are found in ACError.h
                switch ([error code]) {
                    case ACErrorAccountMissingRequiredProperty:
                        NSLog(@"Account wasn't saved because "
                              "it is missing a required property.");
                        break;
                    case ACErrorAccountAuthenticationFailed:
                        NSLog(@"Account wasn't saved because "
                              "authentication of the supplied "
                              "credential failed.");
                        break;
                    case ACErrorAccountTypeInvalid:
                        NSLog(@"Account wasn't saved because "
                              "the account type is invalid.");
                        break;
                    case ACErrorAccountAlreadyExists:
                        NSLog(@"Account wasn't added because "
                              "it already exists.");
                        break;
                    case ACErrorAccountNotFound:
                        NSLog(@"Account wasn't deleted because"
                              "it could not be found.");
                        break;
                    case ACErrorPermissionDenied:
                        NSLog(@"Permission Denied");
                        break;
                    case ACErrorUnknown:
                    default: // fall through for any unknown errors...
                        NSLog(@"An unknown error occurred.");
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                // handle other error domains and their associated response codes...
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
    }];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType]; 
   // [self storeAccountWithAccessToken:@"119745010-g6YqvIdpyvBvYuaweR5oI1V1h9ugIqlj0toetlqg" secret:@"ysBO2E6dgOWj2vKEFoC3PCEypMaPrpycy5WIeodUNro"];



    appDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    chk=appDelegate.chk_login;

    if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
        // create a fresh session object
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
        if (appDelegate.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
            // even though we had a cached token, we need to login to make the session usable
            [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState status,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                // we recurse here, in order to update buttons and labels

            }];
        }
    }


    if ([chk isEqualToString:@"YES"] && (appDelegate.setting_flag==FALSE))
    {

        appDelegate.arr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Change Password",@"Facebook Login",@"Twitter Login",nil];

    }

    else

    {
        if(appDelegate.setting_flag==FALSE) 
        appDelegate.arr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Facebook Login",@"Twitter Login",nil];
    }



}


-(void) updateView
{



}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [appDelegate.arr count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



  cell = [self.SettingsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(!cell)
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];




    if([[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Twitter Login"])
    {




        twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"array=%@",[arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:
                                  [twitterAccount dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"properties"]]];
        NSString *tempUserID = [[tempDict objectForKey:@"properties"] objectForKey:@"user_id"];
        NSLog(@"temp=%@",tempUserID);






        if (!IsEmpty(tempUserID))
        {
            [appDelegate.arr replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Twitter Logout"];
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Twitter Logout";
        }
        else
        {
             cell.textLabel.text=[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }



    }

    else if([[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Facebook Login"])
    {
        if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
            [appDelegate.arr replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Facebook Logout"];
            cell.textLabel.text=[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else
        {
           cell.textLabel.text=[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
        }


    }

    else
    {

         cell.textLabel.text=[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }




    return cell;


}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    if([[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Change Password"] && [chk isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    {   [UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];



        ForgetPasswordViewController *forgetPassView=[[ ForgetPasswordViewController   alloc] initWithNibName:@"ForgetPasswordViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        NSLog(@"Working table");


        [self.navigationController pushViewController:forgetPassView animated:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
        [UIView commitAnimations];



    }

    else if([[appDelegate.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Facebook Login"])
    {
        if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
            // Create a new, logged out session.
            appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
        }
        [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState status,
                                                         NSError *error) {
            // and here we make sure to update our UX according to the new session state
            if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {

            [appDelegate.arr replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Facebook Logout"];
            [self.SettingsTable reloadData];
            }

        }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably get the Access token in this method

```
func loginViewFetchedUserInfo(loginView: FBLoginView, user:FBGraphUser ) {
    println(FBSession.activeSession().accessTokenData.accessToken)
}
```

This code is in Swift, but the method exists for Obj C as well.
Then you would use the access token in the web view as suggested by Sandy and Steve

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `FB access` token, you should be able to use the `Faceboook` `JavaScript` API in your web view.  See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ for the official documentation.  This SO post gives a reasonable explanation: [Retrieve Access Token Using Javascript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126517/retrieve-access-token-using-javascript-api).  As that post describes, you can use the access token in an `AJAX` call directly.  I would not mess with cookies -- just pass along the access token.

You didn't explain exactly what you want to do with `Facebook` in the web view, so I'm not sure this answers your question 100%.  I presume you know how to pass the access token to the web view (`UIWebView's` `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`).

Comment: For embedded webpage, how do u pass an access_token to FB.getLoginStatus() since it doesn't take any param except callback?

Comment: have you actually done this? Theoretically it makes sense but like @Claus i would really like a code sample.