# How can I use an access token to circumvent FB.login()

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, sdk

We are using phonegap to wrap our HTML5 app into a native iOS application. 
We need to login to facebook, but the JS SDK will pop up a Mobile Safari window and, from there, it's a bit weird to go back to the app.

What we want to do is use Facebook's iOS SDK and get an access token and then *somehow* use that token in our JS code to authenticate the user.

Obviously, we still want to use the JS SDK which has been thought out to **not** need tokens.

Do you know how we could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
FB._authResponse.accessToken = 'YOUR TOKEN RETRIEVED FROM iOS SDK'
```

so with access to the UIWebView where your application lives:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                              @"FB._authResponse.accessToken = '%@'",accessToken]
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to pass the token from your native app to your server, so you can initialise the javascript SDK with the access token you received in the native login?

I don't see a specific reason this wouldn't work, you'd just have to POST the access token and associated user info to your server from your native app once the SSO process completes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! POST as in to FB? Is that documented?

Comment: No, i mean once you've obtained the access token in your app, make a request to your server with the access token, and have your app code use that access token to initialise the JS SDK when the user arrives on your web content

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look over the ChildBrowser PhoneGap Plug-in for iPhone?! Especially the [FBConnect example](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser/FBConnectExample)