# Full Facebook login from within UIWebView

Tags: ios, facebook, cookies, authentication, uiwebview

My app needs to have a full login cookie, as well as an API token, in order to fulfill its function. The user is explicitly aware of this and there are no automated actions being executed with their login.

I'll need to do the API login from an internal UIWebView in order for the cookie to be stored within my app. I've looked at the Facebook SDK's

```
[session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView
        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {}];
```

But the animation is very inconsistent with the look of my app. Is there a way to reskin the webView? Will Facebook's SDK block the login cookie?

It seems like I'll have to implement a non-SDK login flow, I'd just like to make sure I'm going about this the right way.

For the record, I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535479/facebook-ios-sdk-with-embedded-uiwebview), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126517/retrieve-access-token-using-javascript-api), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236115/ios-being-logged-in-in-a-webview-after-logging-in-with-the-sdk) and haven't found a sufficient answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use your own logic for implementing graph API endpoints. In this you can customize the views that you want.

You can see below example.

https://github.com/nirmalchoudhari/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API